# Converting AS3 to C# Async Socket not receiving all data

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, sockets, asynchronous

I am porting an AS3 client to C# and am having huge problems with completing the login procedure to the server.

I have no access to the server, just the protocol, and have no idea if the server is expecting any particular behavior with regards the sockets.

I have managed to connect to the server and go through the login process. I have then been able to send a message requesting data which results in a whole series of messages being sent to my client.

In the AS3 version of the client I receive messages in three distinct buffers.

In my C# I only get the first 2 buffers followed by a short period of time and then the connection is reset.

The protocol is binary. First 2 bytes tells me the length of the message, 2nd 2 bytes message type. Rest is data.

On the first read I get a 91 byte policy file which I discard. After that I receive data that I am able to process and the first 20 odd messages are fine. The 3rd buffer though never arrives.

Any ideas? Is it my implementation of AsyncSocket at fault or is there some flag I should be using on my socket?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
public abstract class AsyncSocket 
{
    public class StateObject
    {            
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        public const int BufferSize = 4096;
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        public byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[0];
    }

    public delegate void MessageReceivedHandler(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e);

    public delegate void ConnectedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public event MessageReceivedHandler MessageReceived;

    public event ConnectedHandler Connected;

    private IPAddress[] addresses;
    private int port;
    private WaitHandle addressesSet;
    private Socket socket;
    private int failedConnectionCount;
    private StateObject state;

    public AsyncSocket(IPAddress address, int port) : this(new[] { address }, port) { }

    public AsyncSocket(IPAddress[] addresses, int port) : this(port)
    {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    public AsyncSocket(string hostNameOrAddress, int port) : this(port)
    {
        addressesSet = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        Dns.BeginGetHostAddresses(hostNameOrAddress, GetHostAddressesCallback, null);
    }

    private void GetHostAddressesCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        addresses = Dns.EndGetHostAddresses(result);        
        ((AutoResetEvent)addressesSet).Set();
    }

    private AsyncSocket(int port)
    {   
        this.port = port;
        this.socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);            
        this.Encoding = Encoding.Default;
        this.state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = socket;
    }

    public Encoding Encoding { get; set; }

    public Account Account { get; set; }

    public void Connect()
    {
        if (addressesSet != null)
            addressesSet.WaitOne();            
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref failedConnectionCount, 0);
        socket.BeginConnect(addresses, port, ConnectCallback, socket);
    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
            client.EndConnect(result);
            if (Connected != null)
            {
                Connected(this, new EventArgs());
            }
            Receive(client);
        }
        catch
        {   
            Interlocked.Increment(ref failedConnectionCount);
            if (failedConnectionCount >= addresses.Length)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Send(string data)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetBytes(data);
        Send(bytes);
    }

    public void Send(MsgHead msg)
    {
        byte[] bytes = msg.write();
        Send(bytes);
    }

    public void Send(byte[] bytes)
    {
        int messageLength = BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, 0);
        int messageType = BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, 2);

        Console.Out.WriteLine("Sending:len:{0} msg:{1}", messageLength, messageType);

        socket.BeginSend(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(WriteCallback), socket);
    }

    private void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
        int bytesSent = client.EndSend(result);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);
    }

    private void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {             
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Account.Window.Exit(string.Format("Error on receive: {0}",e.Message));
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)result.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;

        SocketError errorCode;
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(result, out errorCode);
        if (errorCode != SocketError.Success)
        {
            Account.Window.Exit(string.Format("Disconnected, {0}", errorCode.ToString()));
            return;
        }            

        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            Account.Window.Exit("Disconnected, zero bytes");
            return;
        }

        state.messageBuffer = state.messageBuffer.Concat(state.buffer.Take(bytesRead).ToArray()).ToArray();

        int messageLength = BitConverter.ToUInt16(state.messageBuffer, 0);

        if (messageLength > 4096)
        {
            state.messageBuffer = state.messageBuffer.Skip(91).ToArray();
            messageLength = state.messageBuffer.Length == 0 ? 0 : BitConverter.ToUInt16(state.messageBuffer, 0);
        }

        while (messageLength > 0 && state.messageBuffer.Length >= messageLength)
        {
            int messageType = BitConverter.ToUInt16(state.messageBuffer, 2);

            Console.Out.WriteLine("Received:len:{0} msg:{1}", messageLength, messageType);

            if (MessageReceived != null)
            {
                MessageReceived(this, new MessageReceivedEventArgs(state.messageBuffer.Take(messageLength).ToArray()));
            }

            state.messageBuffer = state.messageBuffer.Skip(messageLength).ToArray();

            messageLength = state.messageBuffer.Length == 0 ? 0 : BitConverter.ToUInt16(state.messageBuffer, 0); 
        }

        Receive(client);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes TCP Framing can be tricky. You never know how many receive calls you might get for the three buffers you are expecting. Here are a few things to check:

One problem that could occur in the ReceiveCallback() method, if you only receive 1 byte, your attempt to decode messageLength into a 2-byte Int16 will fail.

Be sure the MessageBuffer methods are all working properly.

Are the 2 bytes for MessageLength included in the value of the MessageLength? If not, be sure to Skip those 2 bytes before decoding the message bytes.

Safer to discard the full number of Message bytes just in case it's not always 91 bytes long.

I would dispatch all "full" message buffers into another method, and discard or handle there, to keep the ReceiveCallback() method nice and concise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added a check to ensure i have at least 2 bytes before calculating the message length. I also used to have a ConcurrentQueue with a BackgroundWorker to process the "full" messages but this made no difference.

What perplexes me is that I just dont receieve the third buffer, what am i doing wrong? Or more likely what behavior is the server expecting?

Comment: Sounds like your data request works fine. I would try counting the total number of bytes received after the initial data request in both clients. If it matches, at least you know the problem is in the C# client's TCP message framing. (I'd be suspicious of checking > 4096 and Skipping 91 bytes, which is too hard-coded).